# Simple Expected value of MLE

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,..., X_n$ be iid $Exp(\lambda)$.

The MLE for $\lambda$ is $\hat{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$, where $\bar{X}=1/n \sum^n_{i=1}X_i$

How can I conclude that $E(\hat{\lambda}) = n\lambda/(n-1)$?

This seems to be very simple, but somehow I'm not getting it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\bar X$?

Comment: @Ilya I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the random variable $S = n \bar X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  Then $S \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(n,\lambda)$ where the parametrization is by rate, not scale.  What is the distribution of $T = 1/S$?  This is inverse gamma:  it is easy to see that $F_T(t) = \Pr[T \le t] = \Pr[1/T \ge 1/t] = 1 - F_S(1/t)$, hence $f_T(t) = f_S(1/t)/t^2$.  I leave it to you to determine how to use this information to obtain ${\rm E}[\hat \lambda]$.

Comment: Many thanks for help heropup. I'm still having some difficulties though.
From your information, I'm trying to integrate $E(T)=\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma (n)}(1/t)^ne^{-\lambda/t}$. I've tried reducing it to another distribution, but with no success...

Comment: I referenced the inverse gamma distribution in case you did not need to derive the expectation of the inverse gamma.  But if you need to prove it, you should proceed directly from the calculation of $${\rm E}[1/S] = \int_{s=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s} F_S(s) \, ds,$$ where $S$ is gamma distributed.

Comment: $F_S$ or $f_S$ in the integral?

If $f_S$, then I get $E(1/S)=\int \lambda^n/\Gamma(n) s^{n-2}e^{-\lambda s} ds=\frac{\lambda}{n}$, which gives $E(\hat{\lambda})=\lambda$...

Comment: Sorry, I inadvertently capitalized the $F$.  It should be the gamma density $f_S(s)$.  Your calculation is not correct.  Check it carefully:  recall that $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ not n!. Thanks ;)